# Include external makefile with CMake

Tags: makefile, cmake

I want to include a makefile from an outside library in my own software's makefile. The simplest would be to figure out the CMake code for the Makefile equivalent of `include ${dir}/makefile` .

But maybe I should give a little context. I'm trying to integrate PETSc (and SLEPc) into my code. Here is some code from an example using SLEPc (although PETSc is pretty much the same):

```
hello: hello.o chkopts
        -${CLINKER} -o hello hello.o ${SLEPC_LIB}
        ${RM} hello.o

include ${SLEPC_DIR}/conf/slepc_common
```

As you can see, it requires an include of a specific makefile that includes a bunch of other makefiles. This is a little weird because it seems like it would've been simpler to just have an include directory, but apparently there's more to it than I understand. Anyway, my first solution was to simply include the makefile it wants and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this requirement **doesn't fit CMake's design model** at all as the Makefiles were generated during the **generation phase** and one of CMake's core principle is to make it **cross platform**, so the better idea might be:

1. Rewrite the external build system in CMake scripts
2. Include the CMake scripts in your project

If the effort is huge, you can try with **add_custom_target/add_custom_command** to do some out of box commands to tweak generated files, but those would also import considerable efforts - just read the manual and seek more opportunities.